# Telegraf json_v2 parser error: Unable to convert field to type int. strconv.ParseInt: parsing invalid syntax

Tags: json, iot, influxdb, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin

Good day!

I have built a small IoT device that monitors the conditions inside a specific enclosure using an ESP32 and a couple of sensors. I want to monitor that data by publishing it to the ThingSpeak cloud, then writing it to InfluxDB with Telegraf and finally using the InfluxDB data source in Grafana to visualize it.

So far I have made everything work flawlessly, but with one small exception.
Which is: One of the plugins in my telegraf config fails with the error:

> parsing metrics failed: Unable to convert field 'temperature' to type int: strconv.ParseInt: parsing "15.4": invalid syntax

The plugins are `[inputs.http]]` and `[[inputs.http.json_v2]]` and what I am doing with them is authenticating against my ThingSpeak API and parsing the `json` output of my fields. Then in my `/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf` under `[[inputs.http.json_v2.field]]` I have added `type = int` as otherwise telegraf writes my metrics as Strings in InfluxDB and the only way to visualize them is using either a table or a single stat, because the rest of the flux queries fail with the error `unsupported input type for mean aggregate: string`. However, when I change to `type = float` in the config file I get a different error:

> unprocessable entity: failure writing points to database: partial write: field type conflict: input field "temperature" on measurement "sensorData" is type float, already exists as type string dropped=1

I have a suspicion that I have misconfigured the parser plugin, however after hours of debugging I couldn't come up with a solution.

Some information that might be of use:
Telegraf version: `Telegraf 1.24.2`
Influxdb version: `InfluxDB v2.4.0`
Please see below for my `telegraf.conf` as well as the error messages.

**Any help would be highly appreciated! (:**

```
[agent]
  interval = "10s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_batch_size = 1000
  metric_buffer_limit = 1000
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  flush_interval = "10s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  precision = ""
  hostname = ""
  omit_hostname = false

[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
  urls = ["http://localhost:8086"]
  token = "XXXXXXXX"
  organization = "XXXXXXXXX"
  bucket = "sensor"

[[inputs.http]]
    urls = [
"https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/XXXXX/feeds.json?api_key=XXXXXXXXXX&results=2"
]
  name_override = "sensorData"
  tagexclude = ["url", "host"]
  data_format = "json_v2"

  ## HTTP method
  method = "GET"

[[inputs.http.json_v2]]

  [[inputs.http.json_v2.field]]
       path = "feeds.1.field1"
       rename = "temperature"
       type = "int"        #Error message 1 
       #type = "float"     #Error message 2
```

Error when type = "float":

```
me@myserver:/etc/telegraf$ telegraf -config telegraf.conf --debug
2022-10-16T00:31:43Z I! Starting Telegraf 1.24.2
2022-10-16T00:31:43Z I! Available plugins: 222 inputs, 9 aggregators, 26 processors, 20 
parsers, 57 outputs
2022-10-16T00:31:43Z I! Loaded inputs: http
2022-10-16T00:31:43Z I! Loaded aggregators:
2022-10-16T00:31:43Z I! Loaded processors:
2022-10-16T00:31:43Z I! Loaded outputs: influxdb_v2
2022-10-16T00:31:43Z I! Tags enabled: host=myserver
2022-10-16T00:31:43Z I! [agent] Config: Interval:10s, Quiet:false, Hostname:"myserver", 
Flush Interval:10s
2022-10-16T00:31:43Z D! [agent] Initializing plugins
2022-10-16T00:31:43Z D! [agent] Connecting outputs
2022-10-16T00:31:43Z D! [agent] Attempting connection to [outputs.influxdb_v2]
2022-10-16T00:31:43Z D! [agent] Successfully connected to outputs.influxdb_v2
2022-10-16T00:31:43Z D! [agent] Starting service inputs
2022-10-16T00:31:53Z E! [outputs.influxdb_v2] Failed to write metric to sensor (will be 
dropped: 422 Unprocessable Entity): unprocessable entity: failure writing points to 
database: partial write: field type conflict: input field "temperature" on measurement 
"sensorData" is type float, already exists as type string dropped=1
2022-10-16T00:31:53Z D! [outputs.influxdb_v2] Wrote batch of 1 metrics in 8.9558ms
2022-10-16T00:31:53Z D! [outputs.influxdb_v2] Buffer fullness: 0 / 10000 metrics
```

Error when type = "int"

```
me@myserver:/etc/telegraf$ telegraf -config telegraf.conf --debug
2022-10-16T00:37:05Z I! Starting Telegraf 1.24.2
2022-10-16T00:37:05Z I! Available plugins: 222 inputs, 9 aggregators, 26 processors, 20 
parsers, 57 outputs
2022-10-16T00:37:05Z I! Loaded inputs: http
2022-10-16T00:37:05Z I! Loaded aggregators:
2022-10-16T00:37:05Z I! Loaded processors:
2022-10-16T00:37:05Z I! Loaded outputs: influxdb_v2
2022-10-16T00:37:05Z I! Tags enabled: host=myserver
2022-10-16T00:37:05Z I! [agent] Config: Interval:10s, Quiet:false, Hostname:"myserver", 
Flush Interval:10s
2022-10-16T00:37:05Z D! [agent] Initializing plugins
2022-10-16T00:37:05Z D! [agent] Connecting outputs
2022-10-16T00:37:05Z D! [agent] Attempting connection to [outputs.influxdb_v2]
2022-10-16T00:37:05Z D! [agent] Successfully connected to outputs.influxdb_v2
2022-10-16T00:37:05Z D! [agent] Starting service inputs
2022-10-16T00:37:10Z E! [inputs.http] Error in plugin: 
[url=https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/XXXXXX/feeds.json? 
api_key=XXXXXXX&results=2]: parsing metrics failed: Unable to convert field 
'temperature' to type int: strconv.ParseInt: parsing "15.3": invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by leaving `type = float` under `[[inputs.http.json_v2.field]]` in `telegraf.conf` and creating a **NEW** bucket with a new API key in Influx.

The issue was that the bucket `sensor` that I had previously defined in my `telegraf.conf` already had the field temperature created in my influx database from previous tries with its type set as `last` (aka: `String`) which could not be overwritten with the new type `mean` (aka: `float`).

As soon as I deleted all pre existing buckets everything started working as expected.

[InfluxDB dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3675U.png)